# Groovy closure DELEGATE_ONLY and DELEGATE_FIRST strategy not working

Tags: groovy

I have the following code snippet in my Demo.groovy file

```
class Person {
    String name
}
def name='no name'
def p = new Person(name:'Igor')
def cl = { name.toUpperCase() }
cl.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY
cl.delegate = p
println cl()
```

According to the Groovy Documentation on closure strategy http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html

I expect the following output

IGOR

However the code seems to print

NO NAME

Can anybody help me understand why does groovy print NO NAME instead of IGOR with resolve strategy set to DELEGATE_ONLY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation says:

> Whenever, in a closure, a property is accessed without explicitly setting a receiver object, then a delegation strategy is involved

This is not the case in your example, where the variable `name`is defined. Remove it, or move it after the definition of the closere and you'll see the expected result

```
class Person {
    String name
}
def p = new Person(name:'Igor')
def cl = { name.toUpperCase() }
def name='no name'
cl.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY

cl.delegate = p
println cl()

IGOR
```

Comment: Hi could you please let me know what is meant by "a property is accessed without explicitly setting a receiver object" and where am I setting a receiver object for the property name.

Comment: @RameshKP I'm sorry I can't. This was simple my interpretation and a result of a test. In case that the `name` was not defined at the time of the closure definition it worked as expected. But there are lots of Groovy experts on this site, so hopefully this will be resolved.

Comment: Actually You are right :) thank you actually def name should be down the closure definition.

Answer (score 0):

This ISNT a very clean example to demonstrate delegation.
In order for delegation to occur correctly we need to have one owner and another delegate.
Refer this for better understanding:

```
def cl = {
    append 'Groovy'
    append 'DSL'
}

String append(String s) {
    println "appending $s"
}

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer()
cl.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY
cl.delegate = sb
println(cl.delegate.class)
println cl()​
```

Here when DELEGATE_ONLY is applied the append() of StringBuffer is called,
else the append method declared in the script is called.